# Finding unique entries of vector and deleting entries outside of interval [cMin, cMax]

Tags: c++

I already managed to implement most of what I planned to do correctly, but somehow I struggle with the unique and cut method.

The unique method should sort the vector and delete all entries that appear more than once and the original vector should be overwritten with the shortened on. The cut method should delete all entries < cMin or > cMax.

Here is my try so far:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Vector {
private:
    int n;
    double* coeff;

public:
    Vector(int, double = 0);
    ~Vector();

    Vector(const Vector&);
    Vector& operator=(const Vector&);

    int size() const;
    double& operator()(int);
    const double& operator()(int) const;

    double max() const;
    void sort();
    void unique();
    void cut(double Cmin, double Cmax);

    void print() const;
};

Vector::Vector(int n, double init)
{
    assert(n >= 0);

    this->n = n;

    if (n == 0) {
        coeff = (double*)0;
    }
    else {
        coeff = new double[n];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        coeff[i] = init;
    }
}

Vector::Vector(const Vector& rhs)
{
    n = rhs.n;

    if (n > 0) {
        coeff = new double[n];
    }
    else {
        coeff = (double*)0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        coeff[i] = rhs.coeff[i];
    }
}

Vector::~Vector()
{
    if (n > 0) {
        delete[] coeff;
    }
}

Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector& rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs) {
        if (n != rhs.n) {
            if (n > 0) {
                delete[] coeff;
            }
            n = rhs.n;
            if (n > 0) {
                coeff = new double[n];
            }
            else {
                coeff = (double*)0;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            coeff[i] = rhs.coeff[i];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

int Vector::size() const
{
    return n;
}

double& Vector::operator()(int j)
{
    assert(j >= 1 && j <= n);
    return coeff[j - 1];
}

const double& Vector::operator()(int j) const
{
    assert(j >= 1 && j <= n);
    return coeff[j - 1];
}

double Vector::max() const
{
    double max = coeff[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (coeff[i] > max) {
            max = coeff[i];
        }
    }

    return max;
}

void Vector::sort()
{ //bubble-sort
    double tmp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
            if (coeff[j] > coeff[j + 1]) {
                tmp = coeff[j];
                coeff[j] = coeff[j + 1];
                coeff[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void Vector::unique()
{
    sort();

    int counter = 0;

    Vector kopie = *this;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i == 0 && coeff[i] != coeff[i + 1]) {
            counter++;
        }
        if (i == n - 1 && coeff[i] != coeff[i - 1]) {
            counter++;
        }
        if (i != 0 && i != n - 1 && coeff[i] != coeff[i - 1] && coeff[i] != coeff[i + 1]) {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    delete[] coeff;
    coeff = new double[counter];

    //to be continued...
}

void Vector::cut(double Cmin, double Cmax)
{
    sort();

    int counter = 0;
    int j = 0;
    Vector kopie = *this;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (coeff[i] >= Cmin && coeff[i] <= Cmax) {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    delete[] coeff;
    coeff = new double[counter];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (kopie.coeff[i] >= Cmin && kopie.coeff[i] <= Cmax) {
            coeff[j] = kopie.coeff[i];
            j++;
            if (j == n) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void Vector::print() const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << coeff[i] << " ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    Vector X(8);

    X.print();
    cout << endl;

    X(1) = 1.;
    X(2) = 7.;
    X(3) = 2.;
    X(4) = 5.;
    X(5) = 6.;
    X(6) = 5.;
    X(7) = 9.;
    X(8) = 6.;

    X.print();
    cout << endl;

    X.sort();
    X.print();
    cout << endl;

    //X.unique();
    //X.print();
    //cout << endl;

    X.cut(2, 6);
    X.print();
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: any reason you can't use `std::vector`? It is a lot easier to work with

Answer (score 0):

For the unique function, rather than checking if it's legal to move the counter forward, I would just check if your current element and the next element aren't the same. If they are, set the next element's pointer to skip over the duplicate element.

Pseduocode:

```
For(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
     if(coef[i] == coef[i+1]) {
         //Keep moving next element pointer until not equal. Probably use a while loop
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution that I can think of is something like this:

```
void Vector::unique()
{
  size_t counter = 0;

  double* copy = new double[n];

  copy[counter++] = coeff[0]; // The first element is guaranteed to be unique

  // Since coeff is sorted, copy will be sorted as well. 
  //   Therefore, its enough to check only the last element of copy to 
  //   the current element of coeff
  for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) 
  {
    if (coeff[i] != copy[counter]) 
    {
      copy[counter++] = coeff[i];
    }
  }

  // copy already contains the data in the format that you want, 
  //   but the reserved memory size may be larger than necessary. 
  //   Reserve the correct amount of memory and copy the data there
  delete[] coeff;
  coeff = new double[counter];

  std::memcpy(coeff, copy, counter*sizeof(double));
}
```

For `cut()` you can use a similar algorithm:

```
void Vector::cut(double Cmin, double Cmax)
{
  size_t counter = 0;

  double* copy = new double[n];

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) 
  {
    if (coeff[i] > Cmin && coeff[i] < Cmax) 
    {
      copy[counter++] = coeff[i];
    }
  }

  // Same story with memory size here as well
  delete[] coeff;
  coeff = new double[counter];

  std::memcpy(coeff, copy, counter*sizeof(double));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you can't use the standard library?

```
void Vector::unique() {
    std::sort(coeff, std::next(coeff, n));
    auto it = std::unique(coeff, std::next(coeff, n));
    double* tmp = new double[n = std::distance(coeff, it)];
    std::copy(coeff, it, tmp);
    delete[] std::exchange(coeff, tmp);
}

void Vector::cut(double Cmin, double Cmax) {
    auto it = std::remove_if(coeff, std::next(coeff, n),
        [=] (double d) { return d < Cmin || d > Cmax; });
    double* tmp = new double[n = std::distance(coeff, it)];
    std::copy(coeff, it, tmp);
    delete[] std::exchange(coeff, tmp);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To remove duplicates and sort, you can achieve it in three ways

Just using vector, sort + unique

```
 sort( vec.begin(), vec.end() ); 
 vec.erase( unique( vec.begin(), vec.end() ), vec.end() );
```

Convert to set (manually)

```
set<int> s;
unsigned size = vec.size(); 
for( unsigned i = 0; i < size; ++i ) 
s.insert( vec[i] ); vec.assign( s.begin(), s.end() );
```

Convert to set (using a constructor)

```
set<int> s( vec.begin(), vec.end() ); 
vec.assign( s.begin(), s.end() );
```

All three has different performance. You can use one depending upon your size and number of duplicates present.

To cut you can use algorithm library

```
std::remove, std::remove_if
```

Syntax

```
template< class ForwardIt, class T >
constexpr ForwardIt remove( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value );
```

Possible implementation

First version

```
template< class ForwardIt, class T > ForwardIt remove(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value) 
{ first = std::find(first, last, value); 
if (first != last) 
for(ForwardIt i = first; ++i != last; ) 
if (!(*i == value)) 
*first++ = std::move(*i); return first; }
```

Second version

```
template<class ForwardIt, class UnaryPredicate> ForwardIt remove_if(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryPredicate p) 
{ first = std::find_if(first, last, p); 
if (first != last) 
for(ForwardIt i = first; ++i != last; ) 
if (!p(*i)) *first++ = std::move(*i); 
return first; }
```

Examples

The following code removes all spaces from a string by shifting all non-space characters to the left and then erasing the extra. This is an example of erase-remove idiom.

Run this code

```
#include <algorithm> 
#include <string> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <cctype>   
int main() 
{ std::string str1 = "Text with some spaces"; str1.erase(std::remove(str1.begin(), str1.end(), ' '), str1.end()); 
std::cout << str1 << '\n';   
std::string str2 = "Text\n with\tsome \t whitespaces\n\n"; str2.erase(std::remove_if(str2.begin(), str2.end(), [](unsigned char x)
{return std::isspace(x);}), str2.end()); 
std::cout << str2 << '\n'; }
```

Output:

```
Textwithsomespaces 
Textwithsomewhitespaces
```